# How to (approach) building user profiles / areas

Tags: angularjs, firebase

**edit: I realise this is a somewhat general post, I am merely looking for some guidance, examples etc.

I have just set out with the goal of (self)learning some deeper web development and have started with Angularjs. I have realised that I learn better when building towards a set project.

With that in mind, I set out to build a relatively simple web app where by users (mainly aimed at Professional chefs) can log in, access their profiles /user area. Users can then add items to a food ingredient database which may include variables such as weight, quantity,price etc. They can then add recipes, drawing from the ingredient database, with the app returning their food cost, tax breakdown as well other predefined calculations.

I have already built the bare bones of the application with Angularjs handling  He various front end routes and layout. 
I have wired the app to use Firebase for the purposes of User authentication and registration components.

As I mentioned, I am mostly self learning and I'd like some pointers on how to implement a user profile area with Angularjs, using Firebase as the back-end database.

**I'd like to achieve the following:**

- after user login, direct to a user specific page
- The user page/area should have abilities such as: profile photo upload, change email, change password etc (usual user operations)

**Once the above is achieved:**

- seperate pages where users can add to their database of ingredients
- seperate page where users can create recipes utilising database items, returning cost breakdown etc.

The user operations page / area is my main concern for the moment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is very general and is going to be largely open to debate and personal preference. If you don't want people to down-vote your question you should ask more pointed and specific questions.

Comment: @DanielC thanks. I realise this is a somewhat general post, I am merely looking for some guidance, examples etc.